# Jquery : How to fetch the parents labels from clicking a Object value?

Tags: jquery

is there any way to get the parents keys from clicking a stored object? pls look in to my html and code :

HTML :

```
<ul id="one">
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul id="two">
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

my Code : and what i want as well :

```
function makeIt(params){
           params.grandParent1.parent1.sector.click(function(){
                console.log(sectorName,parentName,grandParentName) // how can i get this call, simply how can i fetch the key of values?

                // i expected is : sectorName : sector, parentName:parent1,grandParentName:grandParent1...like this
            })
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            params = {
                grandParent1:{
                    parent1:{sector:$('#one').find('li')}
                },
                 grandParent2:{
                    parent2:{sector:$('#two').find('li')}
                 }
            }

            makeIt(params);
        })
```

is this possible? any good way get this done?

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SUG6h/2/

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that? what's wrong with the excellent jQueri API?

Comment: apart from dom, i am fetching the 'li's and keeping it for my own key values to perform application functionality.

Comment: Can you explain what you'd like to accomplish? The js you have written is confusing and invalid.

Comment: i have stored no.of datas in different way, to get data values, it is need some static keyvalues and get data easy from back-end. ect..

Comment: You should look into jquery().data http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this inside `makeit()`:

```
sectorname = Object.keys(this); 
parentname = Object.keys(this.parent); 
grandparentname = Object.keys(this.parent.parent);
```

[More info on Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

As Rick noted below, this isn't supported in IE8 - so you can also get the information using for..in statements to loop through an object's keys.

Comment: can you look in to my jsfiddle?

Comment: `$(params.grandParent1.parent1.sector).click`

Comment: Keep in mind this isn't supported until IE 9. So you'll need to use something like es5 shim.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the DOM yourself and find the parent Nodes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode

If you're already using jQuery for DOM manipulation you should really keep some sort of consistency.